# Rock Paper Scissor Python

Tags: python

I'm Learning Python and coded rock, paper and scissor game.

I'm using IDLE in Ubuntu for this. The code has compiled fine but still i'm unable to get this running. IDLE is running fine in this system. PLease help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import time
import random

rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3

names = {rock:"rock", paper:"Paper",scissors: "Scissors"}
rules = {rock: scissors, paper: rock,scissors: paper}

player_score = 0
computer_score = 0



def start():
    print "Start"
    while game():
     pass
    scores()

def game():
    player = move()
    computer = random.randint(1,3)
    result(player,computer)
    return play_again()
def move():
    while True:
        print
        player = raw_input("Rock = 1 paper = 2 scissor = 3")
        try:
            player = int(player)
            if player in (1,2,3):
                return player
        except ValueError:
                pass
        print "Enter number"

def result(player,computer):
    print "Computer threw {0}!".format(names[computer])
    if player == computer:
     print ("Tie")
    else:
     if rules(player) == computer:
        print("You win")
        player_score += 1

     else:
        print("Computer wins")
        computer_score += 1
def play_again():
    answer = raw_input("Play Again")
    if answer in ("y" "Y"):
      return answer
    else:
        print ("Thanks")

def scores():
    global player_score, computer_score
    print "Player", player_score
    print "Computer", computer_score

    start()
```

Comment: Do you have a question? "I wrote a program that does not work" followed by a code dump is a story (a pretty uninteresting one, too), not a question.

Comment: I was coming here thinking you created a game called rock paper scissors python. But this is just rock paper scissors. I'm so disappointed.

Comment: @WayneWerner This was so promising!!

Comment: Along with the comment, now answer, by @Elazar you've a couple of other issues: your `global` statement belongs in `result()` not `scores()` and `rules(player)` should be `rules[player]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dedent the last line, `start()`. The interpreter runs the upper level of the script, but the indentation makes that line part of the function `score()`.

Comment: Hi Thanks it worked!!